# Angular ng-route and ng-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning front-end and confused with the angular route, should I use ng-view in my application when redirect to another page?( e.g.  login--->homepage)  If ng-view is used, all the other pages will be under , is it a correct way to do the application?

Comment: Your question is too broad.  using `ng-view` is **necessary** with `ngRoute`, but `ngRoute` isn't the only way to redirect to another page.  You should review the documentation, decide if this is how you want your application to work, and ask a more specific question if you still aren't clear.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use `ng-view` in my application when redirect to another page?

Basically, you need to use `ng-view` in order to "change page" when routing. As @Claies said in the comment over, `ngRoute` isn't the only way to redirect to another page, but you should really use it since it's the Angular way and it's already implemented.

> If `ng-view` is used, all the other pages will be under, is it a correct way to do the application?

I don't get your question really clearly but, basically, yes, other pages will be displayed into `ng-view`.
Anyways, you can realize SPAs (Single Page Applications) in this way. Now I'll explain what I mean.

You can **"keep"** a part of a page always present in your view, E.G.:

```
<div class="myHeader"></div>

  <div ng-view=""></div>

<div class="myFooter"></div>
```

Both **myHeader** and **myFooter** will be always present in your view while the content in your **ng-view** changes. You would be able to give both header and footer something like `height: 10%;` and the content of ng-view something like `height: 80%;`.
In this way, the 80% of your page will change when changing route and footer & header will always be the same.

If you have any questions just ask, I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @AndreaM16, that's really helpful : )